# javascript: keep state of javascript effect

Tags: javascript, html

rookie here. i am using basic javascript, css to open/close div by clicking/unclicking on checkbox.

```
function toggleMenu (divId, box) { 
  var vis = (box.checked) ? "block" : "none"; 

  document.getElementById(divId).style.display = vis;
}
```

how do i keep the state of the javascript effect. right now if i click on checkbox to open the div and if i refresh the page or hit back, the page would load with checked box but closed div.

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies would (in my opinion) be the best method of doing this. Check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp

--
When a user checks/unchecks the menu, it can create/change the cookie.

```
document.cookie = "menu_open=yes";
```

Have an onLoad event check their cookies for the menu_open variable:

```
get_cookie ("menu_open");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to add a call to `toggleMenu()` at the end of the page.

The right way is to append it to the `body.onLoad` handler.

The best way is to have a js framework like jquery do the hard stuff so you just add

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     toggleMenu()
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a cookie to save state if toggleMenu is called. Register an onload function to fix up the toggle state by checking the cookie when the page is loaded/refreshed.